# Android sqlite, limit number of rows in database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have new data coming into the app all the time, so I want to limit the number of rows in a table to, say, 100 records. I would describe it as a FIFO queue. Whenever there new data (just a few rows a time) coming in, old data at the 'bottom' of the table are flushed out and deleted. Since it's FIFO, I don't want to manually perform a sort, then delete, then insert back in. I guess there must be cheap way to do this, right? 
Thanks

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Szymon I haven't implemented, but like I said above, easy way to do this is: before inserting, query all data sort by date, then delete oldest records, then insert old and new data back in. But I guess this is not an efficient way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query like this will show all recors, newest first:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Date DESC    -- or some autoincrementing ID column
```

With an OFFSET clause, you can skip the first records.
This means that you get all records *except* the first 100 ones, i.e., you get those records that should be deleted:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Date DESC
LIMIT -1 OFFSET 100
```

You can then use this in a subquery to actually delete the records:

```sql
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID
             FROM MyTable
             ORDER BY Date DESC
             LIMIT -1 OFFSET 100)
```